# Proxy a websocket to hide the IP

Tags: nginx, proxy, websocket

I have a sub domain routed through cloudflare.  They don't cover websockets unless it enterprise or maybe business depending on traffic.

So now when users visit the external site, it connects to my sub domain via a websocket with the url of my site being passed in their url.

```
e.g thridpartysite.com?ws=my.subdomain.com
```

But my IP is revealed and I am worried about DDoS.

I am using nginx and ubuntu 14.04.  Is there anything I can do to mask the IP?

Here is my current nginx config

```
# Config
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my.subdomain.com www.my.subdomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://MySubdomainIP:443;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

So it takes the app on 443 and proxies to 80 so I can route that through cloudflare but no websocket support means I need to reveal my IP which leaves me open to DDoS attacks.

Is there anything I can do at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All plan levels support websoxkets.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-with-WebSockets-